# I've done a shady thing

Tags: c++, incomplete-type

Are (seemingly) shady things ever acceptable for practical reasons?

First, a bit of background on my code. I'm writing the graphics module of my 2D game. My module contains more than two classes, but I'll only mention two in here: *Font* and *GraphicsRenderer*.

***Font*** provides an interface through which to load (and release) files and nothing much more. In my *Font* header I don't want any implementation details to leak, and that includes the data types of the third-party library I'm using. The way I prevent the third-party lib from being visible in the header is through an incomplete type (I understand this is standard practice):

```
class Font
{
  private:
    struct FontData;
    boost::shared_ptr<FontData> data_;
};
```

***GraphicsRenderer*** is *the* (read: singleton) device that initializes and finalizes the third-party graphics library and also is used to render graphical objects (such as *Fonts*, *Images*, etc). The reason it's a singleton is because, as I've said, the class initializes the third-party library automatically; it does this when the singleton object is created and exits the library when the singleton is destroyed.

Anyway, in order for *GR* to be able to render *Font* it must obviously have access to its *FontData* object. One option would be to have a public getter, but that would expose the implementation of *Font* (no other class other than *Font* and *GR* should care about *FontData*). Instead I considered it's better to make *GR* a friend of *Font*.

Note: Until now I've done two things that some may consider shady (singleton and friend), but these are not the things I want to ask you about. Nevertheless, if you think my rationale for making *GR* a singleton and a friend of *Font* is wrong please do criticize me and maybe offer better solutions.

**The shady thing.** So *GR* has access to *Font::data*_ though friendship, but how does it know exactly what a *FontData* is (since it's not defined in the header, it's an incomplete type)? I'll just show the code and the comment that includes the rationale...

```
// =============================================================================
//   graphics/font.cpp
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

struct Font::FontData
    : public sf::Font
{
    // Just a synonym of sf::Font
};

// A redefinition of FontData exists in GraphicsRenderer::printText(),
// which will have to be modified as well if this definition is modified.
// (The redefinition is called FontDataSurogate.)
// Why not have FontData defined only once in a separate header:
// If the definition of FontData changes, most likely printText() text will
// have to be altered also regardless. Considering that and also that FontData
// has (and should have) a very simple definition, a separate header was
// considered too much of an overhead and of little practical advantage.


// =============================================================================
//   graphics/graphics_renderer.cpp
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void GraphicsRenderer::printText(const Font& fnt /* ... */)
{
    struct FontDataSurogate
        : public sf::Font {
    };

    FontDataSurogate* suro = (FontDataSurogate*)fnt.data_.get();
    sf::Font& font = (sf::Font)(*suro);

    // ...
}
```

So that's the shady thing I'm trying to do. Basically what I want is a review of my rationale, so **please tell me if you think I've done something horrendous** or if not confirm my rationale so I can be a bit surer I'm doing the right thing. :) (This is my biggest project yet and I'm only at the beginning so I'm kinda feeling things in the dark atm.)

Comment: I don't understand "a separate header was considered too much of an overhead and of little practical advantage."  What is the overhead?  I'd argue that it is of great practical advantage, since you don't have to declare the struct twice and hope for the correct result.

Comment: writing that comment was surely more work than simply adding an additional header for `FontData`..

Comment: I second James's comment.  The shadiest thing I saw in the entire post was the argument against having a `.h` file that defines a data-structure shared between different parts of the code.

Comment: "Too much overhead" - more to document, one more thing to include, the complexity of the code grows, etc. "Little practical advantage" - `printText()` would have to be modified every time FontData is modified regardless of whether or not it's defined in a separate header or not.

Comment: Up until "the shady thing" I found myself nodding in relieved agreement with all of your rationales. It's refreshing to see! Anyway, I don't really understand the reason for the existence of the surrogate (note: two r's), but the definition of `Font::FontData` looks good to me.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. I think you ought to have written `(sf::Font&)(*suro)` instead of `(sf::Font)(*suro)`; otherwise, I agree with the others: just have a header. :) It'll be encapsulated enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if something looks sketchy, I've found that it's often worth going back a few times and trying to figure out exactly why that's necessary. In most cases, some kind of fix pops up (maybe not as "nice", but not relying on any kind of trick).

Now, the first issue I see in your example is this bit of code:

```
struct FontDataSurogate
    : public sf::Font {
};
```

occurs twice, in different files (neither being a header). That may come back and be a bother when you change one but not the other in the future, and making sure both are identical will very likely be a pain.

To solve that, I would suggest putting the definition to `FontDataSurogate` and the appropriate includes (whatever library/header defines `sf::Font`) in a separate header. From the two files that need to use `FontDataSurogate`, include that definition header (not from any other code files or headers, just those two).

If you have a main class declaration header for your library, place the forward declaration for the class there, and use pointers in your objects and parameters (regular pointers or shared pointers).

You can then use `friend` or add a get method to retrieve the data, but by moving the class definition to its own header, you've created a single copy of that code and have a single object/file that's interfacing with the other library.

**Edit:**
You commented on the question while I was writing this, so I'll add on a reply to your comment.

> "Too much overhead" - more to document, one more thing to include, the complexity of the code grows, etc.

Not so. You will have *one* copy of the code, compared to the *two that must remain identical* now. The code exists either way, so it needs documented, but your complexity and particularly maintenance is simplified. You do gain two `#include` statements, but is that such a high cost?

> "Little practical advantage" - printText() would have to be modified every time FontData is modified regardless of whether or not it's defined in a separate header or not.

The advantage is less duplicate code, making it easier to maintain for you (and others). Modifying the function when the input data changes is not surprising or unusual really. Moving it to another header doesn't cost you anything but the mentioned includes.

Answer (score 2):

`friend` is fine, and encouraged. See C++ FAQ Lite's rationale for more info: [Do friends violate encapsulation?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/friends#friends-and-encap)

This line is indeed horrendous, as it invokes [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior): `FontDataSurogate* suro = (FontDataSurogate*)fnt.data_.get();`

Answer (score 0):

You forward declare the existence of the `FontData` struct, and then go on to fully declare it in two locations:  Font, and GraphicsRenderer.  Ew.  Now you have to manually keep these exactly binary compatible.

I'm sure it works, but you're right, it is kindof shady.  But whenever we say *such-and-such is eeevil*, we mean to avoid a certain practice, with the caveat that sometimes it can be useful.  That being said, I don't think this is one of those times.

One technique is to invert your handling.  Instead of putting all of the logic inside GraphicsRenderer, put some of it inside Font.  Like so:

```
class Font
{
  public:
    void do_something_with_fontdata(GraphicsRenderer& gr);

  private:
    struct FontData;
    boost::shared_ptr<FontData> data_;
};

void GraphicsRenderer::printText(const Font& fnt /* ... */)
{
   fnt.do_something_with_fontdata(*this);
}
```

This way, the Font details are kept within the Font class, and even GraphicsRenderer doesn't need to know the specifics of the implementation.  This solves the `friend` issue too (although I don't think friend is all that bad to use).

Depending on how your code is laid out, and what it's doing, attempting to invert it like this may be quite difficult.  If that is the case, simply move the real declaration of `FontData` to its own header file, and use it in both `Font` and `GraphicsRenderer`.

Comment: Inverting the logic seems a bit backwards to me, besides would Font have to know a bit about the implementation of GR in order for that to work? I guess I'll just end up having a separate header... :)

Comment: @Paul, yes, it is a little backwards, but sometimes that's useful.  Yes, Font would have to know about GR details (perhaps you'd need to make a mix of methods for the two to be able to talk to each other).  If it sounds like too much work, it probably is.  Without knowing details of your code, I can't say.  Basically, this is sometimes a useful technique, so I wanted to point it out.  Separate header file is probably the better way in this instance, but you were looking for another way.

Answer (score 0):

You've spent a lot more effort asking this question then you've supposedly saved by duplicating that code.

You state three reasons you didn't want to add the file:

1. Extra include
2. Extra Documentation
3. Extra Complexity

But I would have to say that 2 and 3 are *increased* by duplicating that code. Now you document what its doing in the original place and what the fried monkey its doing defined again in another random place in the code base. And duplicating code can only increase the complexity of a project.

The only thing you are saving is an include file. But files are cheap. You should not be afraid of creating them. There is almost zero cost (or at least there should be) to add a new header file.

The advantages of doing this properly:

1. The compiler doesn't have to make the definition you give compatible
2. Someday, somebody is going to modify the FontData class without modifying PrintText(), maybe they should modify PrintText(), but they either haven't done it yet or don't know that they need to. Or perhaps in a way that simply hasn't occoured to additional data on FontData make sense. Regardless, the different pieces of code will operate on different assumptions and will explode in a very hard to trace bug.